# Send message to Telegram contact or list of contacts using API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram account and Now I wants to import list of contacts into my Account using Telegram API. 
Is This possible to send Message to my imported contacts using Telegram API, just like normal user can send message to other user in his contacts list?

I tried Telegram bots but Telegram bot can't send message to other users, unless they started any chat with Bot. So this is not that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can act as a normal user by using the Telegram MTProto API. There are many libraries that interact with that, like Python [telethon](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or PHP [MadelineProto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/).